# Opengl Augmented Reality in Android from solvepnp

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, augmented-reality

I am trying to project a 3D surface in opengl on top of a camera view in Android. I am using opencv function solvepnp in native code to get the rotation and translation vectors of the device camera. I use these vectors to calculate the modelView matrix and modelViewProjection matrix as given in the following link:

http://spottrlabs.blogspot.com/2012/07/opencv-and-opengl-not-always-friends.html

Finally, I pass these matrices to the java code in a float array but when I use these matrices in my renderer I don't get the surface projection on the screen. I am sure that my 3D surface is generated properly because when I use an arbitrary value of  modelView and modelViewProjection matrices I can see the projection. But when I use the matrices computed from the solvepnp function I don't get anything. Can someone please tell me where I am wrong? Following are the relevant pieces of my code:

```
"Native code in cpp file"

Rodrigues(r, expandedR);  // r is the rotation vector received form solvepnp function

Mat Rt = Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
   for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      Rt.at<double>(y, x) = expandedR.at<double>(y, x);
   }
   Rt.at<double>(y, 3) = t.at<double>(y, 0);    //t is the translation vector from solvepnp
}
Rt.at<double>(3, 3) = 1.0;

//OpenGL has reversed Y & Z coords
Mat reverseYZ = Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
reverseYZ.at<double>(1, 1) = reverseYZ.at<double>(2, 2) = -1;

//since we are in landscape mode
Mat rot2D = Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
rot2D.at<double>(0, 0) = rot2D.at<double>(1, 1) = 0;
rot2D.at<double>(0, 1) = 1;
rot2D.at<double>(1, 0) = -1;

Mat projMat = Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
float fard = 10000, neard = 5;
float imageWidth=1024.0f;
float imageHeight=576.0f;
projMat.at<double>(0, 0) = 2*scaledCameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 0)/imageWidth;
projMat.at<double>(0, 2) = -1 + (2*scaledCameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 2)/imageWidth);
projMat.at<double>(1, 1) = 2*scaledCameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 1)/imageHeight;
projMat.at<double>(1, 2) = -1 + (2*scaledCameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 2)/imageHeight);
projMat.at<double>(2, 2) = -(fard+neard)/(fard-neard);
projMat.at<double>(2, 3) = -2*fard*neard/(fard-neard);
projMat.at<double>(3, 2) = -1;

Mat mvMat = reverseYZ * Rt;
projMat = rot2D * projMat;

Mat mvp = projMat * mvMat;
float arr[16];
float arr2[16];

int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        arr[count]=(float)mvp.at<double>(i,j);
        arr2[count++]=(float)mvMat.at<double>(i,j);
    }
}

env->SetFloatArrayRegion(sendfloatArray, 0,16, &arr[0]);
env->SetFloatArrayRegion(sendfloatArray, 16,16, &arr2[0]);
```

The following is the code in my Renderer class

```
    // Pass in the modelview matrix ma.mvMatrix received from native code
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvMatrixUniform, 1, false,ma.mvMatrix, 0); 



    // Pass in the modelviewprojection matrix ma.mvpMatrix received from native code
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixUniform, 1, false, ma.mvpMatrix, 0);
```

The following is the code in my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;        // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a 
                            // precision in the fragment shader.



 varying vec4 v_Color;              // This is the color from the vertex shader interpolated across the 
                            // triangle per fragment.


  // The entry point for our fragment shader.
  void main() {                              


  gl_FragColor = v_Color;                                       
}
```

The following is the code in my vertex shader

```
  uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;     // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.                  
 uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;       // A constant representing the combined model/view matrix.              

  attribute vec4 a_Position;        // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.                 
  attribute vec4 a_Color;           // Per-vertex color information we will pass in.                


   varying vec4 v_Color;            // This will be passed into the fragment shader.                


  // The entry point for our vertex shader.  
 void main() {                                                    



// Pass through the color.
v_Color = a_Color;



// gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
// Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in normalized screen coordinates.
gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;                               
}
```

Comment: Did you come up with some answers ??? I have the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
projMat.at<double>(2, 3) = -1;
projMat.at<double>(3, 2) = -2*fard*neard/(fard-neard);
```

Comment: You probably notice that your post does not look ideal, even wrong, if you do not use the info from https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and [edit] accordingly.

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.